# Negative numeric argument in Vim

Tags: vim

Is there a way to apply a vim command backward? For example, I want to kill 5 lines backward, instead of `5dd`, is there something like `-5dd`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `:he d`:

> ["x]d{motion}           Delete text that {motion} moves over [into
>   register
>                           x].  See below for exceptions.

How about <strike>`5dk`</strike> `4dk` (`k` being the motion for upwards)?

Edit: changed count to 4 as this results in 5 lines being deleted apparently...